Gain and SNR of FM demodulation when using orthogonal demodulation
I understand how to theoretically calculate the system performance and signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) for coherent demodulation and envelope demodulation of AM signals. However, calculating the SNR for FM demodulation seems quite challenging, especially when it comes to determining the system gain in quadrature demodulation. Assuming the FM modulated signal is:
$$
s(t) = A_c \cos\left[ \omega_c t + k_f \int_{0}^{t} m(\tau) \, d\tau \right]
$$
How to calculate the output SNR of quadrature demodulation?
Any suggestions or guidance about this question, including links to relevant derivations or calculations, are greatly appreciated.
My approach is to sample the signal using a high-precision ADC and process it in the digital domain. Since the carrier frequency is known, I am considering using IQ quadrature demodulation to shift the carrier signal to zero frequency. Afterward, I plan to apply the arctangent function and differentiation to compute the final signal. I wish to calculate the SNR of this method compared to traditional analog FM discriminator demodulation, and I am curious whether there is a threshold effect in this method.

Hi! Welcome here! "Output SNR": At the output of what exactly? Because saying you have a "quadrature demodulator" is a bit vague there; if you mean the "Bilotti Quadrature demodulator", which is an analog circuit? Or do you mean the principle that you build a filter that has a 90° phase shift (which is very frequency-sensitive, i.e. the phase-over-frequency-curve is steep enough) at the center frequency, and then use an integrating phase error detector as frequency detector? Or do you mean "quadrature demodulator" in the sense of "bringing it (losslessly) to complex equivalent baseband," 1/3

to then process it digitally? (but then, how so?) I'm sorry I'm being a nitpick here, but you're all kinds of right: SNR at the output of an FM demodulator is a bit complicated, and the way to hell is paved with well-intended rules of thumb that forget to mention they don't apply in many cases :) You'll find that when you play with the analog circuitry of an FM radio receiver, a very significant amount of "perceived quality" comes from low-pass filtering the output of the receiver; so, which bandwidth you need to transport is very important. 2/3

So, the problem here is that analog FM audio is a very old system, and terminology has changed; "quadrature demod" in a modern student's text book usually refers to IQ, but for the historical development of FM receivers, that's been having a different meaning starting, if I had to guess, in the 1970s with the advent of integrated circuits in mass products. I'm almost sure that every high-quality FM receiver IC you would buy today is done by very digital means, having a CMOS mixer to some IF, some in-package analog filtering, an ADC and then taking all digital "shortcuts".

@Marcus Müller Thank you very much for your response, and I apologize for any ambiguity caused by my question. You are absolutely correct; the quadrature demodulation I referred to corresponds to what you described as "bringing it (losslessly) to complex equivalent baseband." In my practical situation, the FM baseband signal I receive has a low signal-to-noise ratio (SNR), making analog demodulation quite challenging.

Therefore, my approach is to sample the signal using a high-precision ADC and process it in the digital domain.Since the carrier frequency is known, I am considering using IQ quadrature demodulation to shift the carrier signal to zero frequency. Afterward, I plan to apply the arctangent function and differentiation to compute the final signal. I wish to calculate the SNR of this method compared to traditional analog FM discriminator demodulation, and I am curious whether there is a threshold effect in this method.

I am not very familiar with the modern FM demodulation methods in the digital domain. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

So, in which direction would you like us to point you? Because "SNR at output" really needs us to consider a specific implementation of an FM demodulator. But what you say here suggests that you don't really know how you'd like to demodulate, and that feels like the first thing to solve, then.

But again, your text and your title use "quadrature demodulation" and "orthogonal demodulation", so it feels like you do have a pretty good idea of what you're referring to! I'm just not aware of what that exactly is :) If you could define that in your question, that would be perfect :)
